# Why is my Android navigation drawer opening too wide?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, background-color

I had a rather basic navigation drawer working pretty well -- a simple ListView.  But I need a title above the selectable items, so (see below) modified the XML for the drawer to be a RelativeLayout containing a TextView for a title and then the ListView for the items.

What resulted is quite strange.  Even though I have specified the width for all 3 (RelativeLayout, TextView and ListView) to be 240dp, which was the width of the ListView when it represented the entire drawer's XML, it looks like this (ignore the volume control - didn't see that pop up). Notice the ListView is 240 dp wide, but the red background I've assigned is going all the way to the right.

[image]

Here's my XML for my first screen.  The relevant drawer XML is at bottom.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/ail_background_gradient"
    tools:context="com.allinlearning.assist_android.HomeScreenActivityFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/ail_logo"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="ALL In Learning"
        android:id="@+id/textViewLogo"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size26"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnGradeAssessment"
        android:src="@drawable/grade_assessment"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewGradeAssessment"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textViewGradeAssessment" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Grade"
        android:id="@+id/textViewGradeAssessment"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size28"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imgViewLogo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnPrivateData"
        android:src="@drawable/two_clickers"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBtnGradeAssessment"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgBtnGradeAssessment"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgBtnGradeAssessment" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Private Data"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPrivateData"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size28"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgBtnPrivateData"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBtnPrivateData"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgBtnPrivateData"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="I AM THE TITLE"
        android:id="@+id/tvDrawerTitle"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size26"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvDrawerItems"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `layout_gravity` attribute determines which child `View` acts as the drawer in a `DrawerLayout`. Currently, neither of the direct children of your `DrawerLayout` has that attribute set, so both are just filling it, with the `LinearLayout` on top, covering the content `RelativeLayout`.

Move `android:layout_gravity="left"` from the `ListView` to the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: This would also explain your problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757004/how-to-stop-android-navigation-drawer-from-opening-automatically), which I just saw.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem in both places.  Does it make sense for you to add a specific answer to the other question also so others can benefit?

Comment: Well, I don't think the other question is quite as clear as this one, since it doesn't have the complete layout in the post. You could edit this one to include that other symptom, and just delete the other one. Or you could post the answer yourself. It's up to you how you want to handle it. I don't want to seem like I'm rep farming. :-)

Comment: Well, you're not exactly rep farming when I'm the one who asked that you supply an answer to mark correct.  It's up to you.  I will add the full layout to the other one.  I don't want to add an answer because I didn't come up with the solution.  Thanks though.